# How to get a calculated value from a compiled LambdaExpression?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, telerik, expression

I'm currently working on a project at work, and we are using the Telerik RadControls for Silverlight.  In their Q1 2011 release, they added a new control called the Rad Expression Editor.  In the Rad Expression Editor, you can pass in an object and create formulas (or expressions), and the editor window will give you a preview of the result of the expression.  I've spoken with Telerik about this and they intentionally did not expose the result of this, but mentioned that I could use LambdaExpression.Compile().  I'm very new to Linq and using Lambda Expressions in general, but started looking into this.

As an example, lets say I have an object called Finances, and in that object, there are 4 nullable decimal fields (values): Debit (10), DebitYTD (100), Credit (20) and CreditYTD (200).  In the formula, I want to do something like: Debit - Credit + DebitYTD - CreditYTD.

The Telerik Rad Expression Editor will give me the expression that is generated:
`ExpressionEditor.Expression = {Param_0 => ((Param_0.Debit - Param_0.Credit + Param_0.DebitYTD - Param_0.CreditYTD}`

The result of this expression should be -110.  I need to be able to get the value that is calculate in the expression, but have not been able to figure out how to get this number.  Can anyone please explain how this can be accomplished?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't really told us much about the API which it exposes, but it *sounds* like you could use:

```
var compiled = ExpressionEditor.Expression.Compile();
var result = compiled(input);
```

where `input` is an appropriate variable of type `Finances`.

EDIT: Okay, as the expression isn't exposed nicely:

```
var typeSafe = (Expression<Func<Finance, decimal?>>) ExpressionEditor.Expression;
var compiled = typeSafe.Compile();
var result = compiled(input);
```

Comment: Sorry for leaving some information out, I'm not even really 100% on how to word this correctly.  ExpressionEditor is the Telerik control, and ExpressionEditor.Expression is a LINQ Expression, so I cannot do ExpressionEditor.Expression.Compile() since there's no compile method on it.  Here is what I'm trying to do now:

`LambdaExpression expression = Expression.Lambda(ExpressionEditor.Expression);

var test = expression.Compile();
var mainResult = test(ExpressionEditor.Item);`

Comment: ExpressionEditor.Item is the Item attached to it.  Here's a link to an example of the Telerik Expression Editor:

[link]http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#ExpressionEditor/FirstLook

The Item is what shows up under Fields when looking at the Expression Editor window.

Comment: @Eric: Given that it's expecting a parameter already, you need to create the right parameters... if you print out `ExpressionEditor.Expression.GetType()`, what does it show? Do you *definitely* need to do this with the Telerik classes instead of doing it yourself? (Are you letting the end user edit the expression?)

Comment: @Jon: This is what GetType() shows: `{System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[<namespace>,System.Nullable`1[System.Decimal]]]}`
@Question 2: I'd prefer to just use the Telerik control to do this, but they haven't exposed that value (not sure why not, seems like since they're already calculating it, it'd be pretty easy), but they said to use LambdaExpression.Compile(), except they didn't tell me how.

@Question 3: Yes, the expression is generated by the Telerik control, but the user can change the expression too.  The Telerik control validates the expression as well.

Comment: @Eric: Okay, it looks like you should be able to just cast the expression to `Expression<Func<Finances, Decimal?>>` and then call `Compile`. (`Expression<T>` derives from `LambdaExpression`.) I'll edit the answer.

Comment: @Jon: Thanks for the update.  I'm using:
`LambdaExpression expression = Expression<Func<Finances, decimal?>>.Lambda(ExpressionEditor.Expression);
var compiled = expression.Compile();
var result = compiled.DynamicInvoke();`

Right now I'm still unsure of how to get the actual value that comes this expression.  I tried using .ToDecimal() behind DynamicInvoke(), but it only returns a 0.  I appreciate your help, thanks.

Comment: @Eric: Why don't you use the code I've put in the answer? That way you don't need to invoke it dynamically. Your comment doesn't provide any arguments to the lambda expression though... you'll need to give it some input...

Comment: @Jon: Sorry, I didn't see that you edited your original answer, but awesome, that works the way I was expecting!  Thanks.  I really appreciate it.  You've just saved me a huge headache.  Really really appreciate it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had very similar requirements. There was a need to compile expression and evaluate at runtime against different instances. However function compilation is not so trivial as you have to know the type of the result value during compile time and in most of the cases this will be impossible: user writes "1+1" and you get System.Int32, or user writes "(1+1).ToString()" and you get System.String. I'm sure this is the point where you experience (or will experience) difficulties.

In order to solve the expression compilation problem I would recommend jumping into DLR (Dynamic Language Runtime). You will need to reference "Microsoft.CSharp" assembly for your Silverlight project. As you need just access to "Compile" method for the expression (that is already in there), it will be fair enough doing that against "dynamic" object. Here's a short sample to demonstrate that:

```
  dynamic dynamicExpression = expressionEditor.Expression;
  dynamic compiledExpression = dynamicExpression.Compile();
  object executionResult = compiledExpression(myInstance);
```

The "executionResult" variable will hold the result of expression evaluation. Now you can do whatever you need to do with the result.

Hope that helps