# Telerik Expression control

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, telerik, expression

I am looking to get the calculated result value from the Telerik Expression control. There is a very useful link https://stackoverflow.com/a/5858922/1181910, but i am unable to understand one point in this post. My scenario is the same as mentioned in the above post, but my question is  what is the 'input' variable here? Below is the code from the post (Explained very well by Jon Skeet):

```
var typeSafe = (Expression<Func<Finance, decimal?>>) ExpressionEditor.Expression;
var compiled = typeSafe.Compile();
var result = compiled(input);
```

Here `ExpressionEditor.Expression` will be a LINQ Expression from the Telerik control. I am not sure what should be given for input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type for `ExpressionEditor.Expression` is `Expression<Func<Finance, decimal?>>`. So the input type is `Finance` and the output type is `decimal?`.

The variable `input` must be of type `Finance`. Where it comes from depends on your app, but it must be initialized/set before you use it.

Comment: This was simple but I don't know how I stumbled upon this! Thanks.